# Calculate the line integral $\oint_{C} \frac{2z^3+z^2+4}{z^4+4z^2}dz$, where $C$ is the circle $|z-2|=4$ clockwise watch.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

$\oint_{C} \frac{2z^3+z^2+4}{z^4+4z^2}$

When using partial fractions I have $\frac{2z^3+z^2+4}{z^4+4z^2}$=$\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{2z}{z^2+4}$

Then $\oint_{C} \frac{2z^3+z^2+4}{z^4+4z^2}dz=\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z^2}dz+\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{z^2+4}dz$

Now since $C$ is the circle of radius $4$ and center at $2$ we can see that the singular points are inside $C$.

The singular points are $z=0$, $z=2i$ and $z=-2i$

CAUCHY´S INTEGRAL FORMULA

Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a simply connected domain D. Then for any point $z_0$ in $D$ and any simple closed path $C$ in $D$ that encloses $z_0$

$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_{0}}dz=2\pi i f(z_{0})$

DERIVATIVES OF AN ANALYTIC FUNCTION

If $f(z)$ is analytic in a domain $D$, then it has derivatives of all orders in D, which are then also analytic functions in $D$. The values of these derivatives at a point $z_{0}$ in $D$ are given by the formula

$\oint_{C}\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{n+1}}dz=\frac{2\pi i }{n!}f^{n}(z_{0})$

So applying this to the integrals $\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z^2}dz$ and $\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{z^2+4}dz$ i get

$\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=-2\pi i f^{(1)}(0)=0$

and

$\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{z^2+4}dz=\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{(z-2i)(z+2i)}dz=-2\pi i [f(2i)+f(-2i)]$

where $f(2i)=\frac{2(2i)}{2i+2i}=1$ and $f(-2i)=\frac{2(-2i)}{-2i-2i}=1$

Thus

$\oint_{C}\frac{2z^3+2^2+4}{z^4+4z^2}dz=-2\pi i [1+1]=-4\pi i$.

But I have a huge doubt because apparently the result of the general is zero and I don't know how I can make the integral $\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{z^2+4}dz$ of zero.

Any suggestion? Or is there some mistake that I made to help me see

Comment: What happens if you split up the $z^2 + 4$ using partial fractions?  Everything else looks good to me.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor If I divide it into partial fraction I get that $\frac{2z}{z^2+4}=\frac{A}{z-2i}+\frac{B}{z+2i}$ then $(A+B)z+(2A-2B)i=2z$ so $A+B=2$ and $(2A-2B)i=0$ which it involves $A=B$ then $A=B=1/2$. What it would give me $\oint_{C}\frac{2z}{z^2+4}dz=1/2\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z-2i}dz+1/2\oint_{C}\frac{1}{z+2i}$ And applying the above I get the same result which is $-4\pi i$

Comment: I do not see a mistake here either (modulo on your partial fraction you need A = B = 1). Maybe the reason why "apparently" it has to be 0 is because of a confusion with its a potential antiderivative $\log(z^2 + 4)$?, This doesn't work since you go around 0 and so it is not well defined.

Comment: The way to approach this easiest is to notice $\int z^{-2} = 0$ since there is no residue (no term of order $-1$). The other poles are at $\pm i$, and we have $\frac{2z}{z^2+4} = \frac{1}{z+2i} + \frac{1}{z-2i}$ via partial fractions. The residues are then immediately seen to both be $1$ via the limit definition of residues, after which the result is immediate: since we are traveling clockwise the answer is $-2\pi i$ times the sum of residues, i.e. $-4\pi i$.